# Type switch pattern

Tags: swift, generics

This is the pattern I'm after:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype B
    var type: B.Type { get }
}

protocol P {}
struct X: P {}
struct Y: P {}
struct Z: P {}

struct SwitchP: A { // → error: type 'SwitchP' does not conform to protocol 'A'

    var someContext: Int

    var type: P.Type {
        switch someContext {
        case 1: return X.self
        case 2: return Y.self
        default: return Z.self
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is how to define protocol `A` without raising this ↑ compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, note that a switch over a class hierarchy **does** conform to `A`, but that is too limiting, of course:

```
protocol A {
    associatedtype B
    var type: B.Type { get }
}

class C {}

class X: C {}
class Y: C {}
class Z: C {}

struct SwitchC: A {

    var someContext: Int

    var type: C.Type {
        switch someContext {
        case 1: return X.self
        case 2: return Y.self
        default: return Z.self
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that the following compiles:

```
struct NotASwitchP: A {

    typealias B = P

    var type: P.Protocol { // ← compiles, but should it!?
        return P.self // now we can't return X.self
    }
}
```

... which seems to me to be a compiler bug, which makes the conformance `SwitchP: A` in the question impossible :(

Comment: Don't post comments or updates as answers, update the question instead.

Comment: It is a possible answer - is it not?

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood you. I thought you still wanted an answer to your question.

Comment: Oh, I do, only a better one than my own! Alas, I'm inclined to think of this problem as a Swift grammar bug, but was hoping someone would prove me wrong...